# Left-aligned headers but centered entries in the remainder of the column

Tags: tables

There are three edits that I want for the table the following code gives.

First, I want the column headers left-aligned and the remaining entries in the columns centered.

Second, I would like to put `{\centering\arraybackslash}` in the last column header. (I don't have it in this code because with it the code would not be compiled.  I have seen from other code that I need `newline` or `tabularnewline` is needed at some place.  I don't know the syntax, apparently.)

Third, I am not getting a double vertical bar along the right edge of the table.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|| >{\centering\arraybackslash}l |  >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm} | p{3.5cm} ||} \hline
\multicolumn{5}{|| c ||}{\textbf{Inventory of Clocks and Frequency of Chimes}} \\ \Xhline{0.8pt}
        &   Number of clocks&   Chimes $n$ times on the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ hour  &   Chimes once on the hour     &   Chimes once on the half-hour \\ \hline
Type A  &   10              &   \checkmark                                      &                               &   \checkmark \\ \hline
Type B  &   5               &   \checkmark                                      &                               &   \\ \hline
Type C  &   3               &                                                   &   \checkmark                  &   \checkmark \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\hspace{\fill}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The reason for not getting `||` was explained in your last question: you have specified that to come after the **6**th column, but you only have 5 entries in each row.

Comment: as explained in the last question, if you use `\centering\arraybackslash` then you can use `\\ ` to end the row, as now.

Comment: and as mentioned in comments in the last question putting `\raggedright\arraybackslash` in your headings will make them flush left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}


\centering
% no, use \centering \noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
%  >{\centering\arraybackslash}l you can't apply paragraph settings to a `l`
% entry which is one-line.
% you only have 5 columns not 6, so I deleted the last p{}
\begin{tabular}{||l |  >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}  ||} \hline
\multicolumn{5}{|| c ||}{\textbf{Inventory of Clocks and Frequency of Chimes}} \\ \Xhline{0.8pt}
        &
\raggedright   Number of clocks&
\raggedright   Chimes $n$ times on the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ hour  &
\raggedright   Chimes once on the hour     &
\raggedright\arraybackslash   Chimes once on the half-hour \\ \hline
Type A  &   10              &   \checkmark                                      &                               &   \checkmark \\ \hline
Type B  &   5               &   \checkmark                                      &                               &   \\ \hline
Type C  &   3               &                                                   &   \checkmark                  &   \checkmark \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
% no use \centering\hspace{\fill}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the last `p` column to get the double vertical lines on the right. You are loading `makecell` package and hence use its `\makecell` macro to  left align the headers. Further, when you use `arraybackslash`, you can use `\\` at the end of row.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|| c |  >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm} ||} \hline
\multicolumn{5}{|| l ||}{\textbf{Inventory of Clocks and Frequency of Chimes}} \\ \Xhline{0.8pt}
        &   \makecell[|l]{Number  \\ of clocks}&   \makecell[|l]{Chimes $n$ times \\ on the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ hour \\and here}  &   \makecell[|l]{Chimes once \\ on the hour}     &   \makecell[|l]{Chimes once \\ on the \\ half-hour} \\ \hline
Type A  &   10              &   \checkmark                                      &                               &   \checkmark \\ \hline
Type B  &   5               &   \checkmark                                      &                               &   \\ \hline
Type C  &   3               &                                                   &   \checkmark                  &   \checkmark \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\hspace{\fill}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why isn't "Inventory of Clocks and Frequency of Chimes" centered in your table?  How did you get vertical centering among the column headers?  Is `\usepackage{makecell}` only loaded in the preamble to use `\Xhline{0.8pt` for drawing the one thicker horizontal line in the table?

Comment: @user74973 Because I used `l` column type in `\multicolumn{5}{|| l ||}`, as you said you want it so.  It is `makecell` that does the vertical centering as I have used the `\makecell` macro.

Comment: I said the "column headers are to be left-aligned."  Anyway, I know how to center it.

Comment: OK.  I now see your use of `\makecell` in your code.  It both positions the column headers horizontally - left, center, or right - and centers them vertically.  Thanks.